# Switching workspaces with fullscreen Atom is abrupt

Tags: applications

With Atom in fullscreen mode, switching workspaces to the ones adjacent to to the workspace Atom is in is abrupt. By abrupt I mean that it lacks the smooth moving away of one workspace to the left/right and the other moving in to fill the screen.

While I can move away from the Atom workspace with the proper transition, it is moving back into it that results in it appearing abruptly without any transition at all.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or is it an issue with Atom itself that needs to be dealt with upstream?

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling dynamic workspaces:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior dynamic-workspaces false
```